# How to remove duplicated values on the same row in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have merged 2 DataFrames in pandas, both of them containing the same columns, but with different values on some rows. As example:

```
df1:
     A   B
     1   x
     2   y 
     3   z
df2: A   B
     1   x, y
     2   y, x, z
     4   z
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['A']
```

I was expecting for an output that combined the rows like this:

```
df:
    A   B
    1   x, y
    2   x, y, z
```

But instead, i got something like this:

```
df:
    A   B_x   B_y
    1   x     x, y
    2   y     y, x, z
```

Is there any way that i can get my output somehow like I wanted? I know i can combine both B_x and B_y into a new column and then drop the B_x and B_y columns, but the output wouldn't be the same as I wanted:

```
df['B'] = df['B_x'] +', '+ df[B_y']

df.drop(columns=['B_x', 'B_y']

#The output then will look like this:
df:
    A   B
    1   x, x, y
    2   y, x, y, z
```

Is there any way that I can drop the duplicated values from the same row if I combine these columns like that? Or any way to get an output like the one I want since the beggining?. Sorry if the answer is too obvious, but I'm new using pandas (and also not so experienced in programming), but if you can answer me, it will be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: What if a row in `df1` contains a 'B' value for an 'A' that is not found in 'B' in `df2`?

Comment: I want them to be additive. For example, for the same 'A' value in each DataFrames, imagine that the 'B' value for df1 is 'x' and the 'B' values for df are 'y, z'. I want the 'B' values for the merged DataFrame (df) to be 'x, y, z'.

Comment: So basically the data type of `B` in the columns is set of strings, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `suffixes` to suffix overlapping column names in the left and right side & drop the overlapping column.

```
(
    pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['A'], suffixes=("_x", ""))
        .drop(columns=["B_x"])
)
```

---

```
   A        B
0  1     x, y
1  2  y, x, z
```

Comment: I tried this but the result only keeps the 'B' column that was in df2. What I want is to create a new DataFrame that combines both 'B' columns (for example, if for the same 'A' we have  'B' values of 'x, y' in df1, and 'y, z' in df2, i want the new df to have 'x, y, z' )

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to `expand` the B column into multiple columns, then `melt` it.

```
# Original data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,4], 'B': ['x, y', 'y, x, z', 'z']})
# Expand and melt second dataframe
df22 = (
    pd.concat([df2.A, df2.B.str.split(', ', expand=True)], axis=1)
    .melt('A', value_name='B')
    .drop(columns=['variable'])
    .dropna()
)
# Concatenate data frames and aggreagate
df = (
    pd.concat([df1, df22])
    .drop_duplicates()
    .groupby('A')
    .agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
    .reset_index()
)
df = df[df['A'].isin(df1['A']) & df['A'].isin(df2['A'])]
print(df)
```

will output

```
   A        B
0  1     x, y
1  2  y, x, z
```

Comment: I tried to do it like this, but somehow I always finish with a KeyError on A, so I don't know if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Do you get this error on the dummy dataframe or on the actual dataframe you are working on? You should replace A and B for the real column names of the dataset you are working on.

Comment: Also, in which step of the code you get this error?